# How to match a tuple in a macro

Tags: rust

I'm trying to instantiate lots of `ZbiItemTypeInfo` through a macro, but I get errors that I don't understand

```
struct ZbiItemTypeInfo {
    zbi_type: u32,
    name: &'static str,
    extension: &'static str
}

macro_rules! zbi_new_item_type_info {
    (($a:literal, $b:literal, $c:literal)) => { };
}

zbi_new_item_type_info!(0, "something", "something");
zbi_new_item_type_info!(1, "something2", "something2");
zbi_new_item_type_info!(2, "something3", "something3");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55428d96c08d95d42fcb530ae6751be4)

Error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `0`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:25
   |
7  | macro_rules! zbi_new_item_type_info {
   | ----------------------------------- when calling this macro
...
11 | zbi_new_item_type_info!(0, "something", "something");
   |                         ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

Note that I'm matching against a triplet of `literal`s, so I guess it should work

Comment: You are missing parens around your tuple, making it decidedly not a tuple. Either add parens at call site or remove the extra set in macro definition and don't bother with tuples.

Comment: Actually, neither case would involve tuples at all. If you for whatever reason need an actual tuple you have to match `$expr`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0df2733b02476287949abda30a90695f

Comment: This is what the macro will match `zbi_new_item_type_info!((0, "something", "something"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd is right, the macro will match `zbi_new_item_type_info!((0, "something", "something"));`

For example, the following code works:

```rust
struct ZbiItemTypeInfo {
    zbi_type: u32,
    name: &'static str,
    extension: &'static str,
}

macro_rules! zbi_new_item_type_info {
    (($a:literal, $b:literal, $c:literal)) => {
        {
           let z = ZbiItemTypeInfo{zbi_type: $a, name: $b, extension: $c};
           z
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let o = zbi_new_item_type_info!((0, "something", "something"));
    assert_eq!(0, o.zbi_type);
    assert_eq!("something", o.name);
    assert_eq!("something", o.extension);
}
```